# How to access shapes inside grouped shapes on Google slides using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I found that `getShapes()` does not retrieve the shapes on a Google slide that has been grouped.

For instance, create two shapes on a Google slide. Leave them ungrouped.

[image: A grey circle and a grey rectangle]

When I run the following code, the shapes will be filled with blue, as intended.

```
function myFunction() {
  var deckID = "SLIDE_ID";
  var slide = SlidesApp.openById(deckID).getSlides()[0];

  const blue = "#0000ff";
  const shapes = slide.getShapes();
  if (shapes.length > 0) {
    shapes.forEach(shape => shape.getFill().setSolidFill(blue));
  }
}
```

[image: A blue circle and a blue rectangle]

But if I group them (Right click -> Group, or Cmd + Option + G on Mac), and run the code again, they will remain the same grey color. Logging the array returned by `getShapes()` shows that it is completely empty, meaning grouped shapes are not treated as shapes.

How can I access all the shapes inside a group by code, without having to ungroup the shapes on the slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunctiondd() {
  var deckID = "SLIDE_ID";
  var slide = SlidesApp.openById(deckID).getSlides()[0];

  const blue = "#0000ff";
  const shapes = slide.getShapes();
  if (shapes.length > 0) {
    shapes.forEach(shape => shape.getFill().setSolidFill(blue));
  }

  // I added the below script.
  const processGroups = g => {
    g.getChildren().forEach(c => {
      const type = c.getPageElementType();
      if (type == SlidesApp.PageElementType.SHAPE) {
        c.asShape().getFill().setSolidFill(blue);
      } else if (type == SlidesApp.PageElementType.GROUP) {
        processGroups(c.asGroup());
      }
    });
  }
  slide.getGroups().forEach(processGroups);
}
```

- When this script is run, the shapes in the groups are processed with `getFill().setSolidFill(blue)`.

#### Reference:

- [getGroups()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getgroups)